# What could be the reason for the difference in current and voltage for this transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, circuits

I am supposed to be doing an online engineering assignment and was in the midst of simulating some circuits in Multisim when I noticed something. The placement of the ammeter before and after the resistor yields different values
[image: Picture 1: Ammeter before resistor]
Picture 1: Ammeter before resistor
[image: Picture 2: Ammeter after resistor]
Picture 2: Ammeter after resistor

Also, I noticed that the placement/presence of the ammeter also affects the reading of the multimeter XMM1
[image: Picture 3: Multimeter reading without ammeter present]
Picture 3: Multimeter reading without ammeter present
[image: Picture 4: Multimeter reading with ammeter after resistor]
Picture 4: Multimeter reading with ammeter after resistor
[image: Picture 5: Multimeter reading with ammeter before resistor]
Picture 5: Multimeter reading with ammeter before resistor

What could be the reasons for the current and voltage? This is a dumb question, but I thought that theoretically speaking, the current flowing into and out of a resistor should be the same and that an ideal ammeter should not affect the current whatsoever? Could it be that I connected the components wrongly or is this some quirk of multisim? Thank you for any answers in advance.

Comment: That's really strange, the current loop is the same they should have the same reading

Comment: in the first two diagrams, the ammeters are not connected the same way ... there may be a difference  between the pins

Comment: Possibly some kind of rounding error in the simulation.

Comment: @jsotola Hey there! I followed your advice and changed the circuit simulation so that it would be connected the same. In the end I still got the same results.

Comment: Looks like your ammeter internal resistance is *tiny* **nano-ohm**. Perhaps the voltage drop across this *tiny* resistance is sensed, divided by 1e-9, then reported as amps. You may be running afoul of single-precision float math. Try replacing the ammeter with a 1-ohm resistor, and measuring voltage drop across it (translates directly to AMPS). This may work for low-power circuits like yours, but not for low-voltage, high-current circuits.